# Can Powershell be used to list the contents of a URL directory?

Tags: powershell, webclient

We have a bunch of zip files hosted on an FTP server, which are also accessible via HTTP. I would love to do something like (gci http://test.com/test/ *.zip ) and give me all the zip files which exist on the webserver.

Does anyone know of a way to do such a thing in a clean way?

TIA

Comment: You could hack it together if the `http://test.com/test` had directory indexes enabled but there is no "clean" way of doing it.

Comment: if it´s a ftp server why not use the ftp protocol? you should be able to get a directory listing via ftp from powershell

Comment: I don't want to have the credentials as part of my script if i can help it.

Comment: Seems FTP will indeed be the only way i can do it. Thx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is quite easy with `invoke-webrequest` (PS V3)

```
$r=iwr http://asite.com/test2/ -UseBasicParsing  
$r.Links |?{$_.href -match ".zip"}
```

of course as +arco444 states, the directory index must be enable
[image: directory listing]

---

Edit 
To get the last modified file, you will have to parse the HTML, here is an example (the regex will have to be addapted to your config) :

```cs
$col=@()
$link,$date,$size=""
$r=iwr http://asite.com/test2/ 
$r.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('TR')|%{ 
    $_.getElementsByTagName('TD') |select -expand innerHTML |%{     
        switch -regex ($_){
            "(.)*zip"{ $link = $_;break}
            "\d{2}-...-\d{4}(.)*"{$date=$_;break}
              "^\d*[KM]"    {$size=$_;break }       
            default{}
        }

    }
        if( $link -and $date -and $size){
        $o=new-object -typename psobject |select  -property "link","date","size"
        $o.link=$link
        $o.date=$date
        $o.size=$size

        $col+=$o
        }
    } 
    $col |select -unique "link","date","size" |sort -desc date |select -last 1
```

Comment: But what if there isn't a page with links? Just the files?

Comment: Thx, turns out it's not accessible via http. Damn.

Comment: Kayasazx - got it exposed to HTTP. How do you just list the files without the url in your example? I'll give you the answer. thx

Comment: nevermind, found it: $r.Links.innerHTML |?{$_ -match ".zip" } | Select-Object -Last 1

Comment: You should use the sort-object before the select if you want the newest file

Comment: What to sort on though? Can't sort on name or length. I need the latest file placed out there.

Comment: This is what the HTML looks like, no datetime in a tag, sadly...


    <br> Wednesday, December 24, 2014 11:43 AM    105373669  <A HREF="/test/debug/2.5.1452.1000.zip">2.5.1452.1000.zip</A>
    <br> Wednesday, December 24, 2014 11:56 AM    105393527 <A HREF="/test/debug/2.5.1452.1001.zip">2.5.1452.1001.zip</A>