# Reading the file name of downloaded file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a file containing multiple URLs to files like this:

```
http://ligman.me/1HCDxl9
http://ligman.me/1HCCCRP
http://ligman.me/1HCCCRP
http://ligman.me/1H4Q0e5
http://ligman.me/1H4Q0e5
http://ligman.me/1JI6V77
http://ligman.me/1JI6V77
http://ligman.me/1CSMobd
http://ligman.me/1CSMobd
```

I wanted to write a PowerShell script which will read this file line by line, then download the file behind each line (URL). So far I have managed to download the files using the following script:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\Temp\Ebooks\ebooks.txt") | Where-Object { $_ -ne '' }
$targetDir = "C:\Temp\Ebooks\"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

foreach($file in $reader) {    
    $sourceFileName = $file.SubString($file.LastIndexOf('/')+1) + ".pdf" 
    $targetFileName = $targetDir + $sourceFileName
    $wc.DownloadFile($file, $targetFileName)
    Write-Host "Downloaded $file successfully to directory $targetDir"
}
```

My problem is the file names. Right now, I can only save them as PDF but sometimes, the files aren't PDF files but DOCX or XLSX. Also, it would be nice if they aren't named 1225DID or 13DChwr. Basically, I still need to read the actual file name then save the downloaded file with that name.

How can I do this?

EDIT: This is working for getting the actual filenames, but when I try to open the files I get an error that they're not PDFs or are corrupt (provided I try to open a PDF file with Foxit Reader)

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\Temp\Ebooks\ebooks.txt") | Where-Object { $_ -ne '' }
$targetDir = "C:\Temp\Ebooks\"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$reader | %{    
    $uri = $_
    $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction Ignore   

    $sourceFileName = $request.Headers.Location.SubString($request.Headers.Location.LastIndexOf('/') + 1) 
    $targetFileName = $targetDir + $sourceFileName
    $wc.DownloadFile($file, $targetFileName)
    Write-Host "Downloaded $file successfully to directory $targetDir"
}
```

Comment: Are you able to share an example of one of the actual URLs you are trying to target, or something which has the same format?

Comment: OK I edited to URLs, they should be valid now

Comment: I already tried reading the content disposition of these files but it seems that they only have "attachment" as a value and nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried using `Invoke-WebRequest` to display the contents of the directory? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944884/can-powershell-be-used-to-list-the-contents-of-a-url-directory)

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using fiddler, it seems that there is a redirect behind the scene.

If you execute the following script, you'll get the "real" URLs behind the ones you provided.

```
$links = @(
    "http://ligman.me/1HCDxl9",
    "http://ligman.me/1HCCCRP",
    "http://ligman.me/1H4Q0e5",
    "http://ligman.me/1JI6V77",
    "http://ligman.me/1CSMobd"
)

$links | %{
    $uri = $_

    $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction Ignore
    Write-Host $request.Headers.Location
}
```

This script produces the following list, where you have the document names and their extension.

> ```
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/f/42f9b256-977e-4792-a9eb-d490516d4468/AF103733558_en-us_access2013quickstartguide.pdf
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/5/675609de-a32b-44d4-ace6-86305afb808f/AF103733448_en-us_word2013quickstartguide.pdf
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/8/7/28747b20-70b0-4003-b82a-5ab0d222bbd6/AF103733495_en-us_publisher2013quickstartguide.pdf
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/6/f/e6fc74dc-9f0d-4e6c-bbcc-6855e4d7a78c/AF103733479_en-us_project2013quickstartguide.pdf
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/e/b/ceb742d6-bc1f-4447-ad06-b0842338dd8c/AF103733547_en-us_onenote2013quickstartguide.pdf
> ```

Here is a version downloading files that works for me:

```
$links | %{
    $uri = $_

    $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction Ignore
    $location = $request.Headers.Location
    $output = "D:\temp\" + $location.SubString($location.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $location -OutFile $output
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and I now have the actual filenames. However, I get an error when opening, for example, the PDF files that the file is corrupt. It doesn't matter which one I try to open, it's always the same. Please see my question for updated code.

Comment: Edited answer to give a download example.