# Powershell Invoke-Webrequest to download and save all files?

Tags: powershell

In an attempt to utilize PowerShell to automate a process of pulling down files, doing something with them, and then copying them to somewhere else, I have most of the process working. My only issue I am encountering is I cannot get invoke webrequest to download **multiple** files.

```
# Specify variables

$SVN_BASE = "website ommitted" 
$SCCM_PATH = "path omitted"
$LOKI_PATH = "path omitted"
$INSTALLER_NAME = "Firefox Setup 58.0.1.exe"
$PROJECT_FOLDER = "mozilla_firefox_rr"

# Set an alias for the executable 7zip to be called to extract files

set-alias 7z "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

# Create the working directory for the application

new-item -path "$($env:userprofile)\Desktop" -name $PROJECT_FOLDER -itemtype 
directory -Force

# Change the directory to the working directory 

set-location "$($env:userprofile)\Desktop\$PROJECT_FOLDER"

# Invoke-WebRequest is aka wget. Here, we are downloading the required file
# and placing it into our working directory

Invoke-WebRequest "$SVN_BASE" -outfile ".\"
Invoke-WebRequest "$LOKI_PATH/$INSTALLER_NAME" -outfile 
"$($env:userprofile)\Desktop\$PROJECT_FOLDER\$INSTALLER_NAME"

# Extract contents of executable

7z x Firefox*.exe

# Remove contents that aren't needed

Remove-item .\$INSTALLER_NAME
Remove-item "$SCCM_PATH\core" -recurse
Remove-item "$SCCM_PATH\setup.exe" -recurse

# The final step is copying the newly extracted files to the corresponding SCCM directory

copy-item ".\*" -Destination $SCCM_PATH -recurse
```

The line that I am hoping to utilize to do this is

```
Invoke-WebRequest "$SVN_BASE" -outfile ".\"
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: When you say download multiple files; can you run the `Invoke-WebRequest` multiple times (i.e. once per file's URL); or are you looking to pull back all child items under some remote directory / all linked items from a given page / something like that?

Comment: @JohnLBevan I am looking to pull back the child items under the remote directory. I assumed I can point it to each file, but that would be cumbersome when I have a directory with 50 files for example.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible in a single request; my understanding of HTTP is that each resource needs its own request (this is likely why many people use sprites when there are multiple images on a site, rather than the browser simply downloading the collection of all image files in one request).

Comment: You could pull back a list of links from the remote directory, then pull back each item... That solution's given here (i.e. first part of the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945081/361842

Comment: ps. you can avoid using 7zip and instead use PowerShell (v5 onwards) or .net (pre PS v5) to do the compression.  7-Zip does give better compression; but if you want to avoid any effort working out the relevant path, or having any dependencies outside your control, this option may be better.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347498/361842

Comment: @JohnLBevan the only purpose for 7zip is to extract the contents of the installer.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I forgot one key important part of my script. The $SVN_Base variable is tied to a subversion instance.

Answer (score 6):

Invoke-WebRequest performs HTTP operation with Powershell.

Invoke-WebRequest can perform all HTTP methods. You can accomplish every of them using **Method** parameter (most popular ones are: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

In HTTP protocol there is no option to download all files under particular link. If you want to do it you need to 'crawl' through the page. First list the content of the given link and after some kind of parsing website perform foreach loop through links to download each file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `invoke-webrequest` to find links. You can utilize regex to pull them out. Then you can use `start-bitstransfer` to download each find.